# what happens on connection.setAutoCommit = false

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, autocommit

what happens if I do `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` does it creates a new transaction at database side?

Comment: here is a nice explanation regarding `commit`

Comment: @nafas did you miss to add the link?

Comment: no Idea how I managed to miss it : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/do-inserts-get-auto-committed

Answer (score 9):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html), `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` will allow you to *group* multiple subsequent `Statement`s under the same transaction. This transaction will be committed when `connection.commit()` is invoked, as opposed to after each `execute()` call on individual `Statement`s (which happens if autocommit is enabled).

Changing the auto-commit mode through `connection.setAutoCommit()` will implicitly commit the active transaction and create a new one. From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)):

> NOTE: If this method is called during a transaction and the auto-commit mode is changed, the transaction is committed. If setAutoCommit is called and the auto-commit mode is not changed, the call is a no-op.

Comment: `connection.commit()` ends the transaction but I am curious to know when the transaction is started?

Comment: Actually, changing the auto-commit mode does create a new transaction. I have modified my answer.

Comment: @MickMnemonic what does it mean "If setAutoCommit is called and the auto-commit mode is not changed, the call is a no-op."

Comment: @shiva_R, that means that the method doesn't do anything if e.g. autocommit was already enabled and you call `setAutoCommit(true)`

Answer (score 5):

Let me put it with simple explanation with code. When we have applied

> Connection.setAutoCommit(false);

in our source code, it will disable the autocommit option, which by default enable in database.

So, you have to call

> Connection.commit();

method explicitly to persist any changes to the database.

```
Class.forName(drivers);
Connection dbConnnection=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,username,password);
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false); //Disabling the Autocommit
Statement selectStatement = dbConnection.createStatement("Select Query");
ResultSet rs = selectStatement.execute();
while(rs.next()){
    Statement updateStatement = dbConnection.createStatement("update Query");
    //Apply some changes to update record
    statement.execute();
    dbConnection.commit();  //Mandatory to execute to persist changes into database
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of each method inside JDBC API depends on each driver. Oracle may do something very different than MySql does.

However, only calling `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` doesn't creates a transaction. It only means that any statement created using this connection will be committed together when you call `connection.commit();`.

Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) Oracle tutorial.

Comment: I am just curious to know, so the transaction is started at database side when the first statement is executed?

Comment: Well, it depends on the driver. Each vendor may have a different behaviour.  I don't know where the transaction is started at, but as far as I'm concerned it doesn't matter, because all of the implementations must full fill the requirements of JDBC API.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaDocs provide a nice explanation of this use case in the [Using Transactions Section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

> **Disabling Auto-Commit Mode**
>
> When a connection is created, it is in auto-commit mode. This means
>   that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is
>   automatically committed right after it is executed. (To be more
>   precise, the default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is
>   completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all
>   of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved. In almost
>   all cases, however, a statement is completed, and therefore committed,
>   right after it is executed.)
>
> The way to allow two or more statements to be grouped into a
>   transaction is to disable the auto-commit mode. This is demonstrated
>   in the following code, where con is an active connection:
>
> `con.setAutoCommit(false);`